# display list of vscode search files

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

When I do a search (edit > find in files) in vscode, can I display a list of the files that are being searched? A list or a changing text box that quickly shows filenames being searched.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for this. The closes is opening VS Code with `--log debug` mode so you can see the exact search command used. Why do you need this BTW? Is it not looking for your pattern in some file?

Comment: Thanks, Gino. The reason is because even when I stipulate to search only *.js, after I do a search, the sound of my computer searching my hard drive persists continually thereafter, so I'm wondering what's going on, what it's continuing to search.